# HUE and a JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, hue, apache-drill

I am struggeling with some problems regarding a JAR file and `HUE`. 
The big goal is to use DRILL via `HUE`.

As outlined here it's possible to integrate a database in `HUE`. 
So I try to do this as well. Therefor I downloaded a JAR file and try to integrate this in `HUE`.

So I added a notebook and my code looks like the following lines

```
[notebook]  
show_notebooks=true  
[[interpreters]]  
[[[hive]]] name = Hive interface = hiveserver2  
[[[jdbc]]] name=JDBC interface=jdbc options='{"url": "jdbc:drill:zk=r2c00.pmd.local:2181,r2c01.pmd.local:2181,r2c02.pmd.local:2181/drill/pacluster;schema=pacs2","driver": "org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver","user": "admin","password": "admin"}'
```

I see my notebook called JDBC in the HUE interface under "notebook"

```
select * from pacs2.pacs2.campaign limit 10
```

If I want to execute the following code I get the following error:

> An error occurred while calling z:java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection. : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:drill:zk=r2c00.pmd.local:2181,r2c01.pmd.local:2181,r2c02.pmd.local:2181/drill/pacluster;schema=pacs2 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Obviously `HUE` is not possible to find the driver. Surprisingly if I try to connect to the database via `SQuirrel SQL` it's no problem.

So my key question is where I have to locate the JDBC jar file? Is there a specific location for this file?

I am using `HUE 3.11` and `Cloudera CDH 5.9.0`.

Thanks for all your help!

Peter

Comment: You need to add the right JDBC driver to the classpath of your application.

Comment: Yes, I know... I guess I have the right driver since a connection with Squirrel SQL is possible. The key question is now, how I add this driver to my application - in this case HUE? I found nothing!

Comment: That squirrel has the driver on its class path doesn't mean it is on the class path of other Java applications.

Comment: I know and that's the reason why I ask how I can add a jar file to the classpath used by HUE!

Comment: A quick search leads me to http://gethue.com/custom-sql-query-editors/ (although it uses a way to configure the classpath that is awful and not used by most Java applications). I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes Mark, I found this tutorial as well but in the end this is NOT working for a downloaded JDBC driver. They set the CLASSPATH environment variable in the `.bash_profile` script. Is there any other option to add the set this environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Hue uses a DBProxy service to connect to Drill(and for all JDBC connection). 
Sometimes this service can start multiply times and you need to stop they manually.

1. Check how many DBProxy services is currently running:

   $ ps -e -o pid,command | grep DBProxy

   1503 java -cp /opt/hue-3.11.0/desktop/libs/librdbms/java-lib/dbproxy-1.0.jar: com.cloudera.hue.dbproxy.DBProxy

   1202 java -cp /opt/hue-3.11.0/desktop/libs/librdbms/java-lib/dbproxy-1.0.jar:/opt/drill-1.9.0/jars/jdbc-driver/drill-jdbc-all-1.9.0.jar: com.cloudera.hue.dbproxy.DBProxy

As you can see I have two and one of them is broken (1503).

2. Kill all DBProxy service.

   kill 1503

   kill 1202
3. Restart Hue.
4. All works fine.

My CLASSPATH in this example: **/opt/drill-1.9.0/jars/jdbc-driver/drill-jdbc-all-1.9.0.jar**